# StreamCorruptedException | OptionalDataException in objectInputStream.readObject() in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a Client-Server architecture. The server can have * clients so for each of them two threads (input & output) are created.

I have one master class that coordinates all actions on server side. it has (among others) such a method:

```
public static synchronized void sendMessageToUser(Message message, String username){
    clientOutputThreadPool.submit(new ObjectStreamOutputCallable(userObjectOutputStreams.get(username), message));
}
```

the objectOutputStreamCallable gets the objectOutputStream for the specific user passed (i keep them in a hashmap to reuse them). The callable is executed in a threadpool

the callable looks like this:

```
@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    writeObjectToStream();
    return null;
}

private synchronized void writeObjectToStream() throws IOException {
    oos.reset();
    oos.writeObject(message);
    oos.flush();
}
```

Now I !Sometimes! get the above mentioned errors (on the client side). The fact that this only happens about 30-40% of the time, gets me to believe, that it has something to do with concurrency. Could it be e.g. that the message object that is being serialized is at the same time manipulated somewhere else in the code and that then creates the error? I have read many times that one may not use more than one objectOutputStream or objectInputStream . But I cannot find any place in my code where I use different objectOutputStreams for the same client. Each one has one oos that is created at socket creation time and then kept in a hashmap for later use. also i reset the socket before each message but that still has no effect...

Comment: Show the client side code and the exception's stack trace.

Comment: Synchronize on the `oos` to prevent writing 2 messages at the same time. Synchronization on `writeObjectToStream()` probably has no effect since a new instance is created for each message to write.